# Are these features possible with ROS/Stage?

Tags: simulation, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am interested in implementing the following features into my ROS/Stage project and I would like feedback as far as how feasible these ideas are.  I would appreciate any feedback I can get regarding general information on what I would need to do to accomplish these goals:

1. The ability to select a robot in the Stage simulator with the mouse and perform actions on that robot via ROS commands.  I would need to be able to dynamically choose which robot is the robot on which I am doing certain actions via mouse clicks in Stage.
2. The ability to add/remove robots from the Stage simulation dynamically while running ROS.
3. The ability to add/remove obstacles in the Stage simulation dynamically.  This may simple mean loading a new world file while a simulation is in progress.

Again, I would like to know how feasible these ideas are and/or what general steps might be required to accomplish these goals.  Thank you very much for any information you can provide.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35877/are-these-features-possible-with-ros/stage?/) by [breakspirit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2560/breakspirit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2012-06-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All of those feature should be implementable, with enough work.  You would start by deconstructing the code for stageros and augmenting it with the features that you want.  Basically, you'd end up writing your own ROS wrapper for libstage, with the extra functionality that you want.  I expect that the toughest part will be the graphical selection of robots and execution of ROS code, because that may require modifying libstage's GUI hooks.

Fair warning: you'll be coding in a space that is not well exercised by other people, and so you'll likely end up diving into the libstage code itself to understand what's going on.

Sorry that I can't provide more guidance than that; if I were doing this, I would start by reading the libstage headers to see what's possible.

---

Originally posted by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) with karma: 2916 on 2012-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3